# Can one controller point to different models?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, registration

i am currently developing a login and registration system,
The login system(its own controller, model and view) includes function such as:
validate, if_uname_exists, if_email_exists, etc

registration system(its own controller, model and view) includes functions:
register,send_activation,send_email, etc

However i have a need to make a user controller, which has the username as a data member, and i need to call on functions such as is_admin(), update_profile(). So my doubt is, should those functions be included a user model, or rather can i have them in another model, for example: login model or maybe a profile model?

Are there any best practices to follow on the same?
Thanks alot

Comment: yes one you can can use as many models in one controller, you need to load them $this->load->model('login_model'); $this->load->model('register_model'); $this->login_model->login(); $this->register_model->register();

Answer (score 0):

yes absolutely. one controller many models.

another thing to consider - and note not everyone will approve of this but lets say you have a User model and then you need other models that are related to User but different. you can create a user.php model and then create a folder also named user. your model directory structure will then show your app structure like

```
  user.php 
  user/create.php
  user/emailnews.php
  user/relatedcontent.php
```

this allows you to have shorter model names - and it still all makes sense. typically you would then have abstract methods in the user model and call specifics from the models in the folder. even if emailnews only has one method - breaking it out like that helps to document your application.